# Twitter, FaceBook & Composer Sheet with Kamcord ViewController - cocos2d ios

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have recently integrated Kamcord in my game.. 
Before that, my twitter, facebook and email buttons were working well..

My problem is that I have put all these methods in my default rootViewController.. and now Kamcord forced me to replace my rvc with its own rvc like `window.rootViewController = [[KCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Now my own rvc is not in the scene so I can't see my facebook, twitter and email share sheets..

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by making my root view controller subclass of KamcordViewController..